# Looking for a 90's children's point-and-click minigames game

Tags: identify-this-game

I am looking for a game I played around 25 years ago, which I vaguely remember. It was a point-and-click game, a bit in the style of the Scumm/Director games. As I recall it, it consisted of various small minigames. I think it was in Dutch, possibly by translation. I played it on Windows 95 or 98.

I only recall very few bits and pieces, I hope these are all related to the same game:

1. A minigame where you had a room with on the right side various colored (fantasy) animals (on bookshelves?). There was a phone which you'd pick up and through it somebody described a certain animal. You'd then have to pick the correct one and it would leave through a door to the ouside.
2. A minigame where you would have a drum set which you could click on to play the sounds. I think some kind of anthropomorphic animal (a dog?) sat on the drum throne.
3. A minigame where at the bottom you'd have some spinning gray column which you could 'sculpt' by dragging on the sides. I also associate it with the 'In the Hall of the Mountain King' song, which might have been playing.

Lastly, I think I had two of these games, so perhaps it was a series with at least two games?

Comment: I don't recognise these particular mini games, but I reckon there's a good chance you're after something by Humongous Entertainment - the Putt Putt games were their most well known but coule easily have been one of their products from the sounds of things - Humongous was created by Ron Gilbert who wrote the SCUMM engine.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I looked through all the Humongous games, since I also played a couple of them as well. But alas, none of them are the ones I am looking for. I have just now actually found out with some luck which games they were (by searching for a variety of terms and clicking all through the web). I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching quite a bit, I have found the answer. They are the **Thinkin' Things** educational video game series. Seeing them now they feel a bit less alike the Scumm game implementations. But every point mentioned can be found in either the first or the second game:

1. The fantasy animals and phone minigame can be found in part 1:
   [image]
2. The anthropomorphic drummer minigame can be found in part 1 as well:
   [image]
3. These are not from the same minigame, but part 2 of the series contains a minigame where 'In the Hall of the Mountain King' is playing (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2Sh5pxLSlA&t=1636s). There is a separate sculpting minigame as well:

[image]

Comment: You can accept your own answer.

Comment: @WimC If i remember right there's a delay before OP can do that. I just clicked on the thumbnails to see the full size pictures, only to find they are full sized. Times like this that really cement just how crazy our screen resolutions have gotten since the DOS days!